# Z-index issues, z-index isn't working as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index

My issue is when ever the links are hover, the hidden sub menu pushes the below div with it. I've tried playing around z-index but still no luck. Can someone please help me with this. 
[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/testdrive/8L8rpscd/)

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="top-eybrow">
        <div class="eyebrow-section right text-left">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sign in</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">My acount &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sort-desc dropdown-i fa-fw"></i></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Add listtings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Update my profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">View all listings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">My sales</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Messages</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Help</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix clear-columns"></div>
    <div class="row  clearfix leaderbord-ad">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/upload.uxpin/files/209268/214371/Screen_Shot_2015-06-01_at_4.42.14_AM.png">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.eyebrow-section
{
    margin-right: -45px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100 !important;
}

.leaderbord-ad
{
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -100 !important;
}
```

Comment: z-index works to decide which element shows when two are overlapping.  IT doesn't look like yours are overlapping here, are you sure that is your problem?  Looks like you might want to experiment with display properties on your UL to achieve your menu overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said z-index is not the issue here.
Add this line to your `css`

```
.eyebrow-section ul ul {
    position: absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8L8rpscd/5/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution

```
.leaderbord-ad
{
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adam's answer definitely works, however, when you add additoional elements, they will be out of place relative to the image. In this specific case, I suggest the solution of changing

```
.eyebrow-section
{
margin-right: -45px;
position: relative;
z-index: 100 !important;
}
```

to

```
.eyebrow-section
{
margin-right: -45px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100 !important;
}
```

Then, you can change

```
.leaderbord-ad
{
padding-top: 10px;
position: relative;
z-index: -100 !important;
}
```

to

```
.leaderbord-ad
{
margin-top:35px;
padding-top: 10px;
position: relative;
z-index: -100 !important;
}
```

I find it more logical to manipulate the position of the element that is causing the problem. This allows you to separate the navbar positioning from the positioning of rest of your page elements so anything added will fall inline under your image.